# How can I allow a user to edit a specific system file normally restricted to root?

Tags: permissions, user-management

I am trying to write to `/etc/network/interfaces` with a user that does not have root privileges.

The reason for wanting to write to this would be to allow the user to set a static IP since I am running a command line only server.  What permission do I need to give user in `etc/sudoers`?

I do not want the user to have full root permissions.  Just ability to edit this file.

Answer (score 25):

Instead of using`sudo`, just set an ACL on the file:

```
$ ls -l /var/tmp/foo
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 4 Jul 31 15:26 /var/tmp/foo
$ sudo setfacl -m u:white:rw /var/tmp/foo
$ whoami
white
$ cat /var/tmp/foo
bar
```

Now the file is owned by 'root' but the user 'white' can read and write to it.  The user 'white' can now use his/her favorite editor to edit the file.

Comment: A little confused.  Is `/var/tmp/foo` = `/etc/network/interfaces`?  Never really seen what you are trying to say there, I am pretty new to Linux.

Comment: It's just a file.  You can use whatever file you want.

Comment: Nice. I thought that ACLs could only be used to restrict permissions and not to grant them - nice to know it's not true!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported under WSL: `setfacl: /etc/logrotate.conf: Operation not supported`

Answer (score 8):

Prepare a script that do the editing you want, for example a script that write the correct file with the static IP (what to put in this script is out of the scope of this Q&A). Let's call this script `/root/set_static_ip`. (1)

Edit `/etc/sudoers` (2) (with `visudo` is better, it checks for sanity, it is **very difficult** to recover a system with an invalid  sudoers file, even **impossible** from remote (3)), and add

```
user_name_to_authorize ALL=NOPASSWD: /root/set_static_ip
```

Now that user is able to use `sudo /root/set_static_ip`  without any password asked, and the script will run with all privileges; no other command will be allowed.

If you want the user to just replace a file with whatever they want, the script could simply be (call it `/root/unsafe-overwrite-interface`)

```
#! /bin/bash -e
#
cp /tmp/temp-iface.txt /etc/network/interfaces 
exit 0
```

... and you tell the user to edit `/tmp/temp-iface.txt` and then run `sudo /root/unsafe-overwrite-interface` --- enabling it in sudoers as specified above. Or you can [add the user to an ACL list and give them write permission on the specific file](https://askubuntu.com/a/505165/16395).

But notice that if you do not check the file contents for safety, havoc **will** happen, either intentional or unintentional.

---

*Footnotes*:

(1) this script must be as safe as possible. Check inputs and so on. It will be executed with full permissions.

(2) in modern sudo installation, you can add a file to `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory which is better --- will survive updates.

(3) I normally keep a terminal with a root session open (`sudo -i`) when I modify the sudoers mechanism, and a backup handy.

Comment: The only problem with this is that the static IP settings needs to be changed on demand.  My understanding of the script that you reccomend would basically rewrite the `/etc/network/interfaces` file to whatever the `/root/set_static_ip` is. Unless you can make a script that asks the user to input IP address, gateway, etc... This I am not good enough to make.

Comment: You can write a script that accept parameters... but yes, this is the safest way. If you let the user edit the file blindly, what happen if they make an error? You can have your server out of reach... so the script need not only to ask in some way the parameters, but to check if they are safe.

Comment: Regarding `/etc/sudoers`, it's `visudo`, not `sudoedit`.

Comment: If someone is asking this kind of question, it is probably beyond their skills to write a safe bash script.  There is a reason you cannot setuid root a bash script.