# /etc files security/hardening (sudo)

Tags: permissions, etc

On Ubuntu 22.04, is that possible to deny ALL `/etc` files modifications and grant ONLY specific file(s) running as `sudo`? ex:

```
sudo text-mode-editor-filtered-path /etc/hostname
```

If `/etc/hostname` absolute path is into `/etc/text-mode-editor-filtered-path.conf`, the command above works with root read/write permission(s).

It is like `visudo` (`sudo visudo`). But visudo is only permitted to read/write /etc/sudoers. My idea is to hardening `/etc` files.

On `/etc/sudoers` we could have this:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) /usr/bin/visudo,/usr/bin/text-mode-editor-filtered-path,/usr/bin/anyother-non-text-editor
```

So only `visudo` can edit `/etc/sudoers` and only `text-mode-editor-filtered-path` can edit it's `.conf` containing `/etc` file(s) absolute path.

Any idea?

Comment: Blacklist/whitelist ideas like these don't work well in practice, because often there's no way for you to stop someone from starting the editor with some permitted file, and then using the editor's functionality for opening files to access some disallowed file. Also you can edit whatever file you want with `visudo` using `visudo -f /path/to/file`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I allow a user to edit a specific system file normally restricted to root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505050/how-can-i-allow-a-user-to-edit-a-specific-system-file-normally-restricted-to-roo)

Comment: @muru The "issue" with visudo -f is that sudo_user or member of group_sudo can chance/edit any file into /etc. ACL is more permissive than visudo, so less safe. But we could combine visudo with ACL. Not blacklisting root_user, but allow sudo_user(s) make modifications to specific system file (into etc directory) normally restricted to root. Like we can restrict binaries that can ran with root privileges via sudo command (/etc/sudoers)